# C#: Hide some model properties depending on the objects

Tags: c#, model, polymorphism, .net-core

So basically I have a super class called A, and its subclass are B and C. There is a model class D. Both class B and class C share the same model class D.

However, there's one property called [ID] which does not belong to class C, but it belongs to class B.

How can I "hide" the property [ID] when I am using class C?

Comment: Sharing class definitions would make it more clear to understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: What do you mean by "share the same model class D?" Please provide code examples.

Comment: Please read the guidelines on how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: `C` is not an `A` in that case. You can separate out the `ID` field into an interface like `IHaveID` which `B` implements itself.

Comment: @DanWilson There is a model class D. Both class B and class C use the same model class D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Interfaces:

```
interface IBComposite
{
    int ID {get;}
    string Name {get;set;}
}

interface ICComposite
{
    string Name {get;set;}
}

class D : IBComposite, ICComposite
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

class B
{
    private IBComposite myD;
    public B( IBComposite d ){ myD = d; }

    // Will "see" ID and Name on "myD"
}

class C
{
    private ICComposite myD;
    public C( ICComposite d ){ myD = d; }

    // Will "see" only Name on "myD"
}
```